# Ember.js - Prevent transition if already in app, but redirect if landing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, transition

In Ember.js, when you click on a link inside your app, you can conditionally prevent transitioning to the target page by using `transition.abort()`, for example:

```
  afterModel: function(model, transition) {
    if (!model.user.get('facebookAuthenticated')) {
      if (confirm("You have to log in with facebook. Continue?")) {
        this.controller.send('facebookLogin');
      }
      else {
        transition.abort();
      }
    }
  }
```

This will cancel the transition and you will stay on the current page.

But what if you're landing in the app into this route, for example by following an external URL ? Then the default behaviour is to go ahead and execute `transition.abort()`, which leaves you on a ***blank page***. Not acceptable at all.

Is there a way to detect if the user is landing on this route, so that the app can redirect or something?

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is setting a property on the application route and then setting it to false when the user comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by reading the `transition.sequence` property and using a conditional to redirect/abort transition. The sequence property returns the count of the current transition since landing on the page/loading the ember app.

```
if (transition.sequence === 0) {
  // Land on page
  window.location.replace('http://a.url.com');
}
else {
  // Click link in app
  transition.abort()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the beforeModel hook to check if the user is authenticated.
I am assuming you have some way of knowing if your user is authenticated, either with a session or a cookie.

If the user is not authenticated, you can redirect to another page right away.